# Zend Framework 2 - How to access DB adapter in controller

Tags: php, database, zend-framework2, zend-db

Despite several hits on Google I still couldn't find out how to access the db adapter I configured in my `global.php` in any controller.

I found this:

```
$db = $this->getParam('bootstrap')->getPluginResource('db')->getDbAdapter();
```

But it's giving me a `ServiceNotFoundException`.

Could anybody be so kind to just tell me a quick way to get to the db adapter for making an raw SQL query? (yes, I know that it shouldn't to this but its just temporary)

Thanks!

Comment: Try getting with `$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd access these kind of things through the `ServiceManager`. Try the following:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'); 
// replace 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' with name of adapter if different
```